# I'm not sure if I'm installing GUDHI correctly

Tags: python, python-module

I'm following [this](https://gudhi.inria.fr/python/latest/installation.html) guide to install GUDHI for python. I ran the following commands

```
cd /path-to-gudhi/
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake ..
cd python
make
```

After that, the guide says to do

```
cd /path-to-gudhi/build/python
# May require sudo or administrator privileges
make install
```

But when I run the make install nothing happens, it only returns

```
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
```

And I don't really know if I'm doing something wrong (it's my first time installing a python module). When in python I type

```
import gudhi
```

it returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gudhi'
```

Also when I do

```
make test
```

on the command line, it returns

```
Running tests...
Test project /home/alex/gudhi.3.0.0/build/python
No tests were found!!!
```

What could have gone wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Installing all the dependencies and make it compile can be complicated.
Would the [gudhi conda package](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gudhi) fill your need ? You would just need to install [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) first (in Python 3.X).
And more recently, a [gudhi pip package](https://pypi.org/project/gudhi/) is also available.